# Chances of flipping head 10 times in a row within 1000 flips

Tags: probability

I know how to calculate the probability of flipping a coin 10 times in a row. But how does the probability change when I get 1000 flips?

Comment: Could you write out how you calculated the probability of flipping a coin 10 times in a row?